# WSDL location changed when EJB Web Service was deployed in WAR

Tags: web-services, wsdl, ejb-3.0, java-6

When I deploy my EJB Web service in a WAR file the context of the Service changes.
i.e.
--http://localhost:8080/ServiceName/EJBName?wsdl
Now, it has the web application context->
--http://localhost:8080/WebAppName/ServiceName?wsdl

Why did this change and how do I control the URL of the Web service
I'm using Glassfish3/Java6 and this is what my EJB looks like->

@Stateless
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.foo.bar.Sei",  serviceName = "ServiceName")
public class EJBName implements My {}

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in Glassfish v3 where ejb webservices in war were being treated as webapps. This has been addressed in GF 3.0.1 and the GF 3.1

I updated my Glassfish Server and problem is gone:)